# Rails 3 select and onchange without Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, onchange

I am struggling a whole day with the idea, how to build simple form that contains only select item. This select item will be contains 3 or 4 static values.

I don't know, how to make this form -- I need that after select the item from select offer will the form sent to controller for an action.

I tried to search and reading a lot of articles, but unfortunately I can't find working solution... I don't need an Ajax, just basic functionality.

I would ask you for help, how to do this simple form...
Thank you, 
M.

Comment: do you want to submit the form on changing the select item?

Comment: yes, I do. And the items in select menu can be static (not loaded from database).

Answer (score 0):

add an onclick handler to the select that calls a method that simply submits the form.

Use this method to create the select:

```
collection_select(method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

In the html_options hash put in :onclick => "some_javascript_method()"

in your javascript method have it submit the form.  I would suggest using jQuery to get the form element to call submit on.